# Mock and string array parameter in typemoq

Tags: typescript, mocking

I have a method on a class in a typescript something like this :

```
class validator {
  checkAThing(errors: string[], thing: string): Promise<string[]> {
    // returns a promise
  }
}
```

I want to mock this out using typemoq

So I have something like:

```
let mock = TypeMoq.Mock.ofType(validator);
mock.setup(x => x.checkAThing(??????, TypeMoq.It.isAnyString()))
    .returns((x, y) => {
        return Promise.resolve(x);
     })
```

The problem is I'm not sure how to specify a matcher for the first parameter, the string[], that accepts an array of any strings?

I'm quite happy to use other mocking technologies for typescript if Typemoq can't do it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're just setting up a return and don't care what param values it's called with, then you can just use `It.isAny()`.

```
// will always return the specified value (regardless of what it's called with)
mock.setup(x => x.checkAThing(TypeMoq.It.isAny(), TypeMoq.It.isAny()))
    .returns((x, y) => {
        return Promise.resolve(x);
     })
```

If you really care that your mock is called with a `string[]`, you can use the typemoq's predicate matcher by doing something like this (though it seems like overkill):

```
 TypeMoq.It.is<string[]>(param => 
     Array.isArray(param) && param.every(item => typeof item === "string");
```

https://github.com/florinn/typemoq#setup-mocks

Answer (score 0):

I've tried both It.isAny() and It.is() and get errors.

```
connectionManagementService.setup(x => x.getConnectionGroups(TypeMoq.It.is<string[]>(s => s[0] === Constants.sqlLogin))).returns(() => [conProfGroup]);

Error: the object {
"ctx": {"_args": "[object Arguments]""_property": {"name": "getConnectionGroups"
  "obj": {
    "onAddConnectionProfile": [undefined]
    "onConnectionChanged": [undefined]
    "onDeleteConnectionProfile": [undefined]
    "onLanguageFlavorChanged": [undefined]
  }
} }  "message": [undefined]   "name": "Mock Exception"   "reason": "no setup  expression" } was thrown, throw an Error :)
```